# LibGDX and Typing Label

Tags: libgdx

I am attempting to have animated dialog text for my libGDX game. I found a useful resource on github called Typing Label and i am having some troubled getting it working. Could someone help me with this. Also in the examples it says stage.add and i dont have a stage object declared. what type of object should that be.

```
 TypingLabel label = new TypingLabel("Hello world!", skin);
```

Comment: Your stage  object should be of type 'Stage'.
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d

Answer (score 1):

To use any type of `Actor` (`TypingLabel` is an `Actor`) you need a `Stage` object like the examples say. You also need to draw and update this stage object every game tick so that the Actors can animate and render properly.

```
// Instance variable
private Stage stage;

@Override 
public void create() {
    stage = new Stage(); // Note: There are multiple constructors available
    stage.add(new TypingLabel("Hello world!", skin));

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); // Only needed if you have input such as buttons
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen so we don't get artifacts.  

    stage.act(); // Update all actors
    stage.draw(); // Draw all actors
}
```

The [official libgdx wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) has more information about how to use Stage, Actors, and other parts of Scene2D.